# How to read multiple files using thread pool?

Tags: java, multithreading, file, java-8

I want to read multiple files using a thread pool, but I failed.

```
@Test
public void test2() throws IOException {
    String dir = "/tmp/acc2tid2999928854413665054";
    int[] shardIds = new int[]{1, 2};
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    for (int id : shardIds) {
        executorService.submit(() -> {
            try {
                System.out.println(Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(dir, String.valueOf(id)), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Above is a simple example I wrote. It cannot reach my purpose.

```
System.out.println(Files.readAllLines(
        Paths.get(dir, String.valueOf(id)), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

This line will not run and there were no warnings. I don't know why?

Comment: What is the output that you get ?

Comment: It works on my computer. Are you sure your testing framework works? And you have two files on you computer named:  "/tmp/acc2tid2999928854413665054/1" and  "/tmp/acc2tid2999928854413665054/2"?

Comment: @StephanHogenboom The reason is as tantalum said. I think the code can run on your computer because the files you read is small. So it can obtain a result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are submitting tasks to be executed then ending the test before waiting for the tasks to complete. `ExecutorService::submit` will submit the task to be executed in the future and return immediately. Therefore, your for-loop submits the two tasks then ends, and the test function returns before the tasks had the time to complete.

You might try calling `ExecutorService::shutdown` after the for-loop to let the executor know that all the tasks have been submitted. Then use `ExecutorService::awaitTermination` to block until the tasks are complete.

For example:

```java
    @Test
    public void test2() throws IOException {
        String dir = "/tmp/acc2tid2999928854413665054";
        int[] shardIds = new int[]{1, 2};
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        for (int id : shardIds) {
            executorService.submit(
                    () -> {
                        try {
                            System.out.println(Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(dir, String.valueOf(id)), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        executorService.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //Wait up to 1 minute for the tasks to complete
    }
```